# MS Project Server 2010, JS Grid OnSingleCellClick event not raised in IE9 if not in compatibility mode

Tags: javascript, dom-events, sharepoint-2010, ms-project-server-2010

We're using MS Project Server 2010 and within the timesheet-site, where users can capture working hours, we're attaching to the `OnSingleCellClick` event provided by the JS Grid on this web page.

This works perfectly when the browser IE9 is used in compatibility mode (which it's by default, since it is an intranet site).

But using IE in its standard mode results in not triggering some events of the grid anymore (`OnSingleCellClick`). Strangely though, other events are still fired (for example `OnCellFocusChanged`)

Can anyone confirm this behaviour or point me in a direction what I am doing wrong? I can hardly find any info about this JS Grid ...

Here is a code snippet how we're attaching to the event, but I don't think there can be any error:

```
_grid = satellite.GetJsGridControlInstance();

_grid.AttachEvent(SP.JsGrid.EventType.OnSingleCellClick, CellFocusChanged);
```

Here's a link to the documentation of the JS Grid events:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff681039.aspx